# Why is alert not run even though $.getJSON runs fine? (Callback not executed, even though the request works fine with getJSON)

Tags: jquery, django, jsonp

I have a snippet of code such as:

```
$.getJSON("http://mysite.org/polls/saveLanguageTest?url=" + escape(window.location.href) + "&callback=?",
              function (data) {
          var serverResponse = data.result;
          console.log(serverResponse);
          alert(serverResponse);
});
```

It works fine in the sense that it makes a cross-domain request to my server and the server saves the data as I expect. Unfortunately, even though the server saves data and sends back a response I just can't get any alert or the console.log run. Why may be that? The server side code is (if that is relevant):

```
def saveLanguageTest(request):
    callback = request.GET.get('callback', '')

    person = Person(firstName = 'Anonymous',
                    ipAddress = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    person.save()

    webPage = WebPage(url = request.GET.get('url'))
    webPage.save()

    langTest = LanguageTest(type = 'prepositionTest')
    langTest.person = person
    langTest.webPage = webPage
    langTest.save()

    req ['result'] = 'Your test is saved.'
    response = json.dumps(req)
    response = callback + '(' + response + ');'

    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype = "application/json")
```

What am I missing? (I tried the same code both within my web pages and inside the Firebug and I always have the problem stated above.)

Comment: What do you see in the Response section in FireBug's Net panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your Django code is returning, and not raising an exception? As far as I can see, you have invalid code there - you reference `req['result']` without first defining `req`.

As suggested in the comments, look at Firebug's Console tab to see what is actually being returned from your call. You may find it's actually a Django error page.

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON` likes to fail silently when it received malformed JSON. Check that your JSON is well-formed, or try with a simple tiny bit of JSON to get it working. From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> **Important**: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail
>   silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing
>   of JSON data for this reason. JSON is
>   a data-interchange format with syntax
>   rules that are stricter than those of
>   JavaScript's object literal notation.
>   For example, all strings represented
>   in JSON, whether they are properties
>   or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON
>   format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: I'd be double checking to make sure the json is well formed

Answer (score 0):

My bad' I've forgotten to add

```
req = {}
```

before

```
req ['result'] = 'Your test is saved.'
```

(And another failure on my side was to implement an error handling function for the callback, if that's possible at all for jQuery's default JSONP functionality).